# How can I make combn work in dplyr::mutate?

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm trying to make `combn()` work in `dplyr::mutate`, but I'm failing and can't quite figure out why.

This works:

```
c("a", "b", "c") %>% combn(2, FUN = paste, collapse = ";", simplify = TRUE)
[1] "a;b" "a;c" "b;c"
```

But how can I make this work?

```
tribble(
  ~col, 
  c("a", "b", "c"), 
  c("a", "d", "f")
) %>% 
  mutate(col = combn(str_split(names, ";"), 2, FUN = paste, collapse = ";"))
```

I want each row in the matrix to be a character vector in this form:

```
[1] "a;b" "a;c" "b;c"
```

The example above would be the first row.

Edit: I guess it's fine if `combn()` isn't used.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We could use `map` to loop over the `list` and `paste`

```
library(tidyverse)
out <- tribble(
    ~col, 
     c("a", "b", "c"), 
     c("a", "d", "f")
   ) %>% 
      mutate(col = map(col, ~ combn(.x, 2, FUN = paste, collapse=";")))
```

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
  tribble(
      ~col,
      c("a", "b", "c"),
      c("a", "d", "f")
    ) %>%
      rowwise() %>%
      mutate(new = toString(combn(col, 2, FUN = paste, collapse = ";")))
```